# Get column and row of object in GridLayout with an index

Tags: java, indexing, row

I have 100 JButtons in a 10x10 GridLayout and added all buttons too in a List. How do i get the column and row of a specific button (from index)? I already tried different for-loops and maths but it didn't worked ...

Comment: We need to see some code -how they're added to your list and what you've tried and how it failed

Comment: They are added like this:

`for (int i = 0; i < layout.getColumns() * layout.getRows(); i++) {

JButton button = new JButton(i+"");

add(button);

list.add(button);

}
`.





I tried this:
`for(int y = 0; y < layout.getRows(); y+= layout.getColumns()) {
   for(int x = 0; x < Columns(); x++) {
    if(button.equals(list.get(x + y / Columns()))) {
     System.out.println("Found! "+x+":"+y);
    }
   }
  }`

Comment: Thanks, but please edit it into your question, formatted, so it's easy to help you out. In particular - we're also going to need to know also what type of `List` object your `list` variable is.

Comment: Something along the lines of int row = index / layout.getColumns();
int col = index % layout.getColumns();

Comment: ´I have 100 **JButtons** in a 10x10 GridLayout and added all buttons too **in a List**.´

It's A List<JButton> ...
(I edited it but it automaticly formats the comment) :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer THANK YOU! :D It worked (with +1 at the end)

Comment: Remember, in most cases, java is 0 index, 0x0 is the first row/column position of the grid, but if you want to display then value in a human friendly manner, then yes, you'll need a +1

Comment: I know that it mostly starts with 0. But it was supposed to display it to the user (who usually starts from 1 to count).

Comment: How can i get the opposite result? (Get index from row and column)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag attribute to get row and col. So your upper left corner tag would be 0000, lower left tag would be 9999.

```
Public void btnTapped(View v){

    Button btn = (Button) v;
    String rowcol= btn.getTag().toString();
    int row = Integer.parseInt(rowcol.substring(0,2));
    int col = Integer.parseInt(rowcol.substring(2));
```

}